# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 does NOT include Self Registration (Sign-Up) Page?

Tags: wso2, registration, wso2-identity-server

In some previous WSO2IS versions, there was a default self sign-up feature.
However, I could not find it in the 5.0 version.

Reading the WSO2IS 5.0 documentation, what I have found is 2 APIs used for this feature:

> getUserIdentitySupportedClaims() ­- Set of claims to which the user profile details should be saved in the Identity Server.
>
> registerUser() -­ This registers a user in the system. You need to pass values like user name, password, claim attributes and values returned from the previous call and the tenant domain. The confirmation code is sent by email to the given email address.

So, the self sign-up feature is hidden somewhere OR do I need to implement it by myself?
And is there any example of using APIs for this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is available in the dashboard:

```
https://<url>:9443/dashboard/
```

You can use the following service for signing up users:

```
https://<url>:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService?wsdl
```

Note that in WSO2 products, admin services WSDL's are hidden by default. You can expose them by setting HideAdminServiceWSDLs parameter to 'false' in `<IS>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`.